# iText pdf methods not getting exposed in ASP.NET Core C# application - GetNumberOfPages, GetPage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, itext, nuget-package, itext7

I'm using iText pdf library to process PDF files using C# in an ASP.NET Core application.

I'm getting following errors while using GetNumberOfPages and GetPage methods.

> Error CS1061  'PdfReader' does not contain a definition for 'GetNumberOfPages' and no accessible extension method 'GetNumberOfPages' accepting a first argument of type 'PdfReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error CS1061  'PdfReader' does not contain a definition for 'GetPage' and no accessible extension method 'GetPage' accepting a first argument of type 'PdfReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have used both iText and iText7 nugget libraries

[Please check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt6Nv.png)

```
List<byte[]> chunks = new List<byte[]>();

using (MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes))
{                
    using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfStream))
    {
        int pageCount = pdfReader.GetNumberOfPages();

        for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
        {
            using (MemoryStream chunkStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(chunkStream))
                {
                    using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
                    {
                        pdfDocument.AddPage(pdfReader.GetPage(i).CopyTo(pdfDocument));
                    }
                }
                chunks.Add(chunkStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried both iText and iText7 but issue isn't resolved

Comment: The error messages are correct, there are no such methods of `PdfReader`. There are such methods of `PdfDocument`, though.

Comment: Hi@gaurav sharma，any update here?

Answer (score 0):

1.The methods `GetNumberOfPages` is not directly available on the `PdfReader` class in **iText 7**. Instead, you should use the `PdfDocument` class.

2.Instead of using `GetPage`, use `pdfDocument.CopyPagesTo(i, i, newPdfDocument)` to copy a specific page to a new document in **iText7**.

A whole working demo you could follow:

```
List<byte[]> chunks = new List<byte[]>();
using (MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes))
{
    using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfStream))
    {
        using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader))
        {
            int pageCount = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages();

            for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
            {
                using (MemoryStream chunkStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(chunkStream))
                    {
                        using (PdfDocument newPdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
                        {
                            
                            pdfDocument.CopyPagesTo(i, i, newPdfDocument);
                        }
                    }
                    chunks.Add(chunkStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
                        
    }
}
```